# Careers location search broken

Tags: bug, search

Location search in Careers has been broken for several hours.

Compare [Los Angeles](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&searchTerm=ruby&location=90001&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles) to [New York](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=p&searchTerm=ruby&location=10001&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles), for example. Duplicate results appear without location or distance constraints. (The same searches had been working perfectly earlier today, so it isn't a matter of semi-relevant results appearing correctly.)

Comment: this is true. I can't upvote it though because I'm not meta enough. Filtering by "offers visa sponsorship" or "offers relocation" also doesn't work.

Comment: Still not working as of today, both with zip codes and named locations (first results show "MA, IL, South Africa, Denmark, India" no matter the location).

Comment: Same number of jobs showing up within 20 miles regardless of whether my search location is "Chicago", "Tokyo, Japan", or "Antarctica".  Location search is totally broke.

Comment: Ok, it appears to be fixed as of this writing--location searches are again returning filtered results.